# Excel VBA starting a Sub

Tags: vba, excel

How would I start the below code?

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate 
    'Can't select unless the sheet is active 
Dim Title As Integer, result As String 
titleDetail = Range("A1").Value 
If titleDetail = "Title" Then result = "Hyperlink" 
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Value = result
```

Any script always has to begin with either Private Sub, Public Sub, etc. correct? How do I determine which to use?

Secondly, when I declare my range (titleDetail = Range("A1").Value) right now its only going to look in cell A1 correct? What would be the proper syntax to look through any cells from A1:C150?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the range `A1:C150`. You should qualify your ranges. `So ThisworkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C150")`. There are a bunch of ways to short cut this as well

Comment: This is a very broad question - have you [searched at all?](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+vba+private+sub+public+sub)  There are myriad sources explaining the various ways to call a subroutine.  While it's a totally separate question (and should be asked in a separate question...but do research first please) To look through cells, you need a loop: `Dim myRng as Range, cel as Range // set myRng = Range("A1:C150") // for each cel in myRng // ' do whatever with cel // next cel`

Comment: `Sub` denotes an executable procedure that defines a scope. If no access modifier is specified, your procedure is implicitly `Public`. Best make it an early habit to be explicit about such things, and always do `Public Sub`. Use the `Private` modifier when the procedure only needs to be visible (/invoked from) the module it's written in - that's useful for breaking down your script into small, named steps that the caller doesn't need to care about, i.e. `Public Sub DoTheThing()` might be calling `Private Sub DoStepOne()` and `DoStepTwo()`. Use descriptive names starting with a verb!

Comment: You "start" a procedure by attaching it to a shape in some worksheet ("assign macro..."), or by invoking it from an *event handler* procedure, by name - e.g. `DoSomething` invokes procedure `DoSomething`. With parameters, `DoSomething "abc", 42` passes string literal value `"abc"` to the first parameter, and integer literal value `42` to the second parameter. The signature for `DoSomething` in that case might look like `Public Sub DoSomething(ByVal thing As String, ByVal foo As Long)`.

Comment: That said, an entire *book* could be written to properly answer everything you're asking for - that's slightly too broad to be a good fit for this site, unfortunately.

Comment: @urdearboy Thank you for the responses, they did help. Ill do a bit more research before asking questions like this is in the future. This is my second day on this site, and i'm attempting to teach myself VBA - ill be sure to be more specific in my questions for the future.

Comment: @brucewayne same as above

Comment: @MathieuGuindon same as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub RunThis()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        .Offset(1, 0).Value = IIf(.Value = "Title", "Hyperlink", "")
    End With
End Sub
```